# How to draw a diagram with arrows facing each other using tikz-cd?

Tags: arrows, tikz-cd

I want to have the four objects, with lines facing opposite directions and with lines facing each other as such:[image]

I'm quite new to tikz-cd and I was wondering how to do this, especially with aligning the middle objects and the arrows facing each other.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE: have you tried to read the guide of the tikz-cd package?

Answer (score 1):

```
\begin{tikzcd}
                         &    & {+} \arrow[rd,red] \arrow[ld,red] \arrow[dddd,<->] &    &                                                    \\
                         & {} &                                       & {} &                                                    \\
{-} \arrow[ru,red] \arrow[rd,red] &    &                                       &    & {-} \arrow[lu,red] \arrow[ld,red] \arrow[llll,<->,crossing over] \\
                         & {} &                                       & {} &                                                    \\
                         &    & {+} \arrow[lu,red] \arrow[ru,red]              &    &                                                   
\end{tikzcd}
```

hope that is helpful,
[image]

Comment: https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/ and this is a website too useful to draw freely your diagrams and you should know some commands to modify color and crossing over arrows from here  http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf